# Storing the state through Batches in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tensor

I am facing a problem in tensorflow that am trying to store information throughout batches. I know that this is possible in RNN via the stateful flag but I am trying to implement a custom layer that functions differently than an RNN and cannot make it work:

```
class SquareLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, shape):
    super(SquareLayer, self).__init__()
    self.shape = shape

  def build(self, input_shape):
    return
    
  def call(self, inputs, subtract): 
    square = tf.square(inputs[ :-1, 30:, 0:0] - subtract[ 1:, 30:, 0:0])
    output = tf.concat([square, inputs[ :-1, 30:, 2:]], 2)
    return output

inputs = Input(shape=(1372,9))  
cnn1   = Convolution1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=2, batch_input_shape=(None, 1372, 9))(inputs)
flatten= Flatten()(cnn1)
dense1 = Dense(1372)(flatten)
out1 = Dense(1)(dense1)

square1 = squareLayer(1344)(inputs, out1)
cnn1   = Convolution1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=2, batch_input_shape=(None, 1344, 1))(square1)
flatten= Flatten()(cnn1)
dense1 = Dense(1372)(flatten)
out2 = Dense(1)(dense1)

out3 = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(normal_dist)(Concatenate([out1, out2]))

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out3)
model.compile()
```

So essentially in the SquareLayer, I am trying to subtract from the current input (inputs[ :-1, 30:, 0:0] in call) the out1 Layer, shifted by 1. This generally compiles, however, how can I make so when I train it, the information is stored throughout batches, because all the out1 parameters are resetted after every batch iteration. I tried creating object variables but they are also deleted. How can the information be preserved though iterations?

Comment: it's very though to help you since half of the explanation is missing... to begin with, what i `ev`??

Comment: hi sorry, ev is supposed to be out1. i have changed it. i fixed the code. does this clear up the code?

Comment: yes, but no... what are you willing to store for the whole training process? `out1` is the result of of anon linear transformation of the corresponding input, aka the corresponding batch... thus, it's not clear what you want to achieve, since from your code it's not clear what you want to use as "constant" throughout the whole learning process